# How to read multiple attributes using xpath and based on that trigger the jenkins job

Tags: xml, xpath, jenkins

I am having an xml file(executeRM.xml) with contents as mentioned below.

```
<r1> <n1 name="component1" version="14.0" state="ToBeInstalled"/> <n2 name="Component2" version="13.0" state="Installed"/> <n3 name="Component3" version="12.0" state="TobeInstalled"></r1>
```

I have used "FS trigger-Monitor files" and is an every one minute schedule, where I have given the full path of the above xml file. Now I want to write an xpath query, which will trigger the job only when state will be "ToBeInstalled" for any of the 3 components or all. I have written the below xpath query, but the job itself is not getting triggered.

```
/r1/n1[@name='Component1' and @state='ToBeInstalled'] /r1/n2[@name='Component2' and @state='ToBeInstalled'] /r1/n3[@name='Component3' and @state='ToBeInstalled']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the FSTrigger help:

> Poll the content of the specified XML file. You have to give XPath
>   expressions. A build is triggered if the value of XPath expressions
>   have changed between 2 polls.

Are you sure your xPath

```
/r1/n1[@name='Component1' and @state='ToBeInstalled'] /r1/n2[@name='Component2' and @state='ToBeInstalled'] /r1/n3[@name='Component3' and @state='ToBeInstalled']
```

is correct? what you have seems like 3 separate xPaths.

Even if you just use `/r1/n1[@name='Component1' and @state='ToBeInstalled']` this just selects n1, a node that has no text value, so it never changes (that's just my theory).

I was able to get it to trigger by just using 
`/r1/n1/@state` for example, but I don't think this will give the control you want (and you may get multiple builds triggered).

I think you need more information on how the *value of XPath expression* is evaluated. You might ask the maintainer for further information at the [plugin site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin).

Comment: Hi ptha, You are absolutely right. At any point of time if any one or all three(it may get increased to 6-7) conditions hold good then I should be able to trigger the build. If I use /r1/n1/@state, multiple build get triggered. So either I have to use the proper Xpath query or should use some other trigger mechanism. Please suggest me if I can play with xpath queries or better go for some other method. But the XML structure remains constant, I may have to add few nodes, but the attributes remain the same. for any component, if the attribute value is "ToBeInstalled", build should get triggered.

Comment: @Sachidananda you may have to use something like the Script Trigger plugin, or if your executeRM.xml file is in your source control repository you could use some sort of commit hook to trigger the Jenkins job and avoid polling altogether. As I said you will have to talk to the developer of FSTrigger to get more information on that.